# nmcli wifi access point isn't showing up

Tags: networking, network-manager

I've created an access point using nmcli however it isn't showing up .

```
user@user:~# sudo nmcli connection


NAME                UUID                                  TYPE                  DEVICE 
(green) Wired connection 1  00000000-000-0000-0000-000000000000  802-3-ethernet   eth0   
(green) wifi-wlan0          11111111-111-1111-1111-111111111111  802-11-wireless  wlan0  
(white) wlan0               22222222-222-2222-2222-222222222222  802-11-wireless  --
```

`wifi-wlan0` is configured as the access point however it doesn't show up on as a WiFi network.

```
 root@orangepizero:~# nmcli connection show wifi-wlan0
 connection.id:                          wifi-wlan0
 connection.uuid:                        11111111-111-1111-1111-111111111111
 connection.interface-name:              wlan0
 connection.type:                        802-11-wireless
 connection.autoconnect:                 no
 connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
 connection.timestamp:                   1494274782
 connection.read-only:                   no
 connection.permissions:                 
 connection.zone:                        --
 connection.master:                      --
 connection.slave-type:                  --
 connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
 connection.secondaries:                 
 connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
 connection.metered:                     unknown
 connection.lldp:                        -1 (default)
 802-11-wireless.ssid:                   iot
 802-11-wireless.mode:                   adhoc
 802-11-wireless.band:                   --
 802-11-wireless.channel:                0
 802-11-wireless.bssid:                  --
 802-11-wireless.rate:                   0
 802-11-wireless.tx-power:               0
 802-11-wireless.mac-address:            --
 802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address:     --
 802-11-wireless.mac-address-blacklist:  
 802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization:default
 802-11-wireless.mtu:                    auto
 802-11-wireless.seen-bssids:            
 802-11-wireless.hidden:                 no
 802-11-wireless.powersave:              default (0)
 ipv4.method:                            shared
 ipv4.dns:                               
ipv4.dns-search:                        
ipv4.dns-options:                       (default)
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv6.method:                            ignore
ipv6.dns:                               
ipv6.dns-search:                        
ipv6.dns-options:                       (default)
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
GENERAL.NAME:                           wifi-wlan0
GENERAL.UUID:                           a629217a-36a8-44ce-a91f-dfaa042d4a37
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        wlan0
GENERAL.STATE:                          activated
GENERAL.DEFAULT:                        no
GENERAL.DEFAULT6:                       no
GENERAL.VPN:                            no
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/0
GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT:                    /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/23
GENERAL.MASTER-PATH:                    --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.42.0.1/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::de44:6dff:fe30:4d5d/64
IP6.GATEWAY:
```

Comment: The question seems to gloss over important details, like that the second output example is from a separate device, and how you "created an access point using nmcli".  Further, the second output seems to indicate that the separate device is in fact connected to `wifi-wlan0`, so it's not clear what the question is asking/why you think the AP is not showing up.